# Why do ImageButtons appear smaller than their actual size?

Tags: android

I want to use ImageButtons with a vector graphic instead of text in my app.

First observation: the ImageButton does not automatically scale the graphic to fit onto the button. It does that only if I specify a scale type like `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

Second observation, and this is a real problem: the ImageButton does not "fill" its entire size with background color or the vector graphic information. There is always an empty "border" around it.
See the screenshot below:

- the first row are ImageButtons without `android:scaleType`, the
  second row uses  `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.
- the first column uses `settings_vec.xml`, a vector graphic which is too
  large for the buttons (and therefore must be scaled down), the second column uses `settings_tiny_vec.xml`,
  which approximately fits on the button.
  Only the upper-left ImageButton is displayed in its full size, the others are smaller as the selection frame indicates.

I tried with `android:src` and with `app:srcCompat`, same behaviour. And same behaviour for PNG graphics, and same goes for normal Buttons (with the `android:icon` property).
I also tried different scale types, same behaviour.
Different paddings only influence the padding between the *visible* edge of the background and the vector graphic.

My current workaround is to make the ImageButtons larger so that the *displayed* size is what I want.

**So my questions are**:

1. How can I force an ImageButton to fully use its requested (constrained) size?
2. Does anybody know whether this behaviour is the same for all API
   levels? Would be no fun to maintain different layouts to get around
   this...

I use Android Studio Iguana on Windows, and testing with API level 30. The behaviour is the same in AS Designer and in my app.

---

[image: Screenshot AS Designer]

---

style definition:

```
<style name="TestStyle">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#FFCCCCCC</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">8dp</item>
</style>
```

---

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="ImageButton\nw/o scaleType"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Vector Vector(tiny)"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/row1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_vec"
    style="@style/TestStyle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/row1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/row1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_tiny_vec"
    style="@style/TestStyle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imagebutton1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imagebutton1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="w. scaleType"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imagebutton1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton5"
    android:src="@drawable/settings_vec"
    style="@style/TestStyle"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/row2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/row2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton6"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_tiny_vec"
    style="@style/TestStyle"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imagebutton5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imagebutton5" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was as simple as to specify `android:background` as well (not only `android:backgroundTint` as in the code above)!

Answer (score 0):

If you set a default theme for `ImageButton` (`@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton`) and go to inside via `Ctrl + Click`, you see that it has background property with default implementation `@drawable/btn_default_material`. And the end point is `shape` with padding equal to `8dp`.

```xml
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
       android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
           android:tint="?attr/colorButtonNormal">
        <corners android:radius="?attr/buttonCornerRadius" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
                 android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Therefore you can set `padding` to `0dp` or `background` to transparent.

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="" />
```

Comment: Hi @Viewed, I did set `android:padding="0dp"` and it did not help. Setting the background to transparent only hides the problem because you don't see that the ImageButton displays too small. And I do want to have a visible background on my buttons.